# ImageMagick convert SVG to PNG not working with RSVG enabled

Tags: svg, imagemagick, png, rsvg

I'm using ImageMagick's `convert` utility to convert SVG file to PNG image. At first, I used vanilla installation of IM on OSX (`brew install imagemagick`) to convert the SVG using:

```
$ convert file.svg file.png
```

This worked except that some of the image objects in that file were offset (actual links to images). I then [read a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658872/svg-to-png-conversion-with-imagemagick-doesnt-handle-defs) that suggested ImageMagick to be compiled with **rsvg** support (homebrew does it with `brew install imagemagick --use-rsvg`).

Now, when I try to perform the conversion, no images are rendered. I tried using [this SVG file](http://croczilla.com/bits_and_pieces/svg/samples/arcs1/arcs1.svg), and the resulting PNG was blank. However, if any text exists on the SVG, it's rendered in the proper location. Any ideas how to proceed? thanks.

Comment: Try Inkscape. If you install that on your system, Imagemagick will use it automatically over RSVG or MSVG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I now had a look at [the SVG file](http://croczilla.com/bits_and_pieces/svg/samples/arcs1/arcs1.svg) you linked to.

It contains JavaScript. I do not think that the RSVGlib does support JavaScript inside SVGs. I know for sure that the internal SVG coder named *MSVG* does not.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also tried it on a file that contained only images and text.

Answer (score 20):

You should run this command to see a list of all *'delegates'* your ImageMagick is trying to use:

```
 convert -list delegate
```

To discover which delegate command ImageMagick uses for SVG processing, run

```
 convert -list delegate | grep 'svg ='
```

You should see the binary + commandline parameters your `convert` tries to use. Im my case it is `/opt/local/bin/rsvg-convert` (but I'm not using Homebrew, I use MacPorts).

Now check if the binary is present at all on your system:

- If yes, run it directly and debug from there.
- If no, try to find where your Homebrew installation installed it, and change ImageMagick's  configuration file for its delegates. It's called *delegates.xml*. MacPorts places it into `/opt/local/etc/ImageMagick/delegates.xml` -- I don't know where Homebrew stores it.

However, since your un-modified installation was already working, there *must have been* an SVG consuming delegate at work already then. Otherwise you would not have gotten any SVG processed ***at all***.

This internal SVG rendering method of ImageMagick is called MSVG. This is far from being a feature-complete SVG interpreter/renderer.

---

**Update:**

To see what ImageMagick is doing for which format, run this command:

```
convert -list format
```

and for SVG run

```
convert -list format | grep SVG
```

Output on my system is:

```
 MSVG  SVG       rw+   ImageMagick's own SVG internal renderer
  SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.36.1)
 SVGZ  SVG       rw+   Compressed Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.36.1)
```

After you installed `rsvg`, the internal method to render SVGs will not have gone away. You can still force ImageMagick to use the internal renderer by adding `MSVG:` to the commandline like this:

```
convert  MSVG:file.svg  file.png
```

Just for completeness' sake...

Comment: I also have `/usr/local/bin/rsvg-convert`, specifically:
`$ convert -list delegate | grep`

`    cdr =>          "uniconvertor" "%i" "%o.svg"; mv "%o.svg" "%o"`

`    svg =>          "rsvg-convert" -o "%o" "%i"`

Comment: Has your `/usr/local/bin/rsvg-convert` the executable bit set? Does it work on the commandline with the command given, i.e.: `/usr/local/bin/rsvg-convert -o out.png in.svg`?

Comment: Thanks again for following up on this. I have the exact same output as you do when running `convert -list format | grep SVG`, and when running `convert MSVG:file.svg file.png` I do get the output with the images, albeit they're offset somewhat (which was my original problem). `rsvg-convert`, which is sym-linked to `/usr/local/Cellar/librsvg/2.36.1/bin/rsvg-convert`, has 755 permissions.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem and was just told to install inkscape and it works,

[ImageMagick converts svg graph into pdf with tilted x-axis labels, any ideas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555563/imagemagick-converts-svg-graph-into-pdf-with-tilted-x-axis-labels-any-ideas)

The delegate list did not change but the output did. On further fiddling with forced MSVG I could not get the problem to go away. So another delegate is probably the best solution.