# Use librsvg / rsvg to convert SVG images with ImageMagick

Tags: macos, svg, imagemagick, homebrew, librsvg

I know this question has several answered version here (like this: [ImageMagick convert SVG to PNG not working with RSVG enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592085/imagemagick-convert-svg-to-png-not-working-with-rsvg-enabled) ), but actually I can't find a real solution to my exact problem. My problem is: I have a specific SVG file (and I will generate more) that ImageMagick inside SVG>PNG convertor process doesn't convert perfectly. So I need to change it to **librsvg**, because it does, I tested these 2 lines with different result:

```
    convert test.svg test.png  // ( img: http://tinyurl.com/px2lw3v )
    rsvg-convert test.svg -o test.png // ( img: http://tinyurl.com/lreu6sk )
```

I installed HomeBrew. As described here: [ImageMagick convert SVG to PNG not working with RSVG enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592085/imagemagick-convert-svg-to-png-not-working-with-rsvg-enabled) I used this code to install ImageMagick `brew install imagemagick --use-rsvg`. I realized that it not installs **librsvg** so I needed to uninstall it and reinstall like this: `brew reinstall imagemagick --with-libsrvg librsvg --use-rsvg` : this installed imagemagick & librsvg together to my mac. BUT doesn't connected them:  `convert -list format | grep SVG` resulted as:

> ```
>  MSVG  SVG       rw+   ImageMagick's own SVG internal renderer
>   SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (XML 2.9.0)
>  SVGZ  SVG       rw+   Compressed Scalable Vector Graphics (XML 2.9.0)
> ```

while this: `convert -list delegate | grep svg` resulted as:

```
    svg =>          "rsvg-convert" -o "%o" "%i"
```

I installed & uninstalled & reinstalled them several times & ways but nothing changed and the script `convert test.svg test.png` do it's way without librsvg. I added lines to /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-1/lib/ImageMagick/config-Q16/configure.xml with tags but nothing progressed. I don't know what to do and how to connect ImageMagick and force to use different library for `convert test.svg test.png`.

Thank you for your help.

More information:

```
    $ which convert
    /usr/local/bin/convert

    $ convert -version
    Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-1 Q16 x86_64 2014-05-12 http://www.imagemagick.org
    Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
    Features: DPC Modules
    Delegates: bzlib freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png xml zlib

    $ otool -L $(which convert)
    /usr/local/bin/convert:
        /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-1/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
        /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-1/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
        /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.2.0)
        /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.3.0)
        /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.5)
        /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
        /usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)

    $ which rsvg-convert
    /usr/local/bin/rsvg-convert

    $ otool -L $(which rsvg-convert)
    /usr/local/bin/rsvg-convert:
        /usr/local/Cellar/librsvg/2.36.3/lib/librsvg-2.2.dylib (compatibility version 39.0.0, current version 39.3.0)
        /usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 3001.0.0, current version 3001.8.0)
        /usr/local/lib/libgio-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 4001.0.0, current version 4001.0.0)
        /usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 3601.0.0, current version 3601.5.0)
        /usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 3601.0.0, current version 3601.5.0)
        /usr/local/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 4001.0.0, current version 4001.0.0)
        /usr/local/lib/libcairo.2.dylib (compatibility version 11203.0.0, current version 11203.16.0)
        /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib (compatibility version 29.0.0, current version 29.0.0)
        /usr/local/lib/libcroco-0.6.3.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.1.0)
        /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.9.0)
        /usr/local/lib/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 4001.0.0, current version 4001.0.0)
        /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 4001.0.0, current version 4001.0.0)
        /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.2.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

- ImageMagick 6.6.9-1
- Mac OS X 10.9.4

Comment: If you install Inkscape on your system, ImageMagick will use it automatically. It does not need to be installed as a delegate. It is usually better than RSVG.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Just adding more context to Zoltan's answer)

Use `brew info imagemagick` to see available options when installing it.

```
--with-librsvg
    Build with librsvg support
```

Comment: homebrew option --with-librsvg no longer supported.  I get error

Answer (score 16):

I tried and my solution is on Mac:

1. run `brew doctor` and `brew update`
2. use simply `brew reinstall imagemagick --with-librsvg` // - you may misspelled!
3. try it. it should work!

Is it work?

Comment: hi zoltan can you look at this related question? your post helped me successfully get it working locally but there are text nuances on server that preclude success right now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789732/converting-svg-to-pdf-and-downloading-small-errors-in-svg-text-elements

Comment: This answer appears to be outdated- current homebrew gives error `Error: invalid option: --with-librsvg`

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use Homebrew to install imagemagick with svg support, you need to use an older version.  They removed options from the installation process early 2019.

```
    brew install https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/raw/46a2ef7c9f0380b8e19f8dfe37270caa27581353/Formula/imagemagick.rb --with-librsvg
```

Comment: Or, [compile from source](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-unix.html) since "GraphicsMagick may be compiled from source code for virtually any modern Unix system ([including Linux and MacOS X](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/README.html#installation))"

Answer (score 2):

The --with-librsvg option is no longer supported. Instead librsvg is its own package now and will install the rsvg-convert command.

```
brew install librsvg
```

For reference https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/librsvg#default