# ImageMagick converts svg graph into pdf with tilted x-axis labels, any ideas?

Tags: pdf, svg, imagemagick

I just installed Bionic Beaver on an old computer and am running it nicely off of a USB stick. I believe I have the most recent release of everything right now. After getting latex running I tried to convert an svg plot into pdf using imagemagick like I often do. This however produced a bit of spurious output. I could probably dig into it a little, in the past I have had to look at other tools to get the detail from the SVG preserved in the PDF, but thought it was an odd enough problem to be of more interest. I did note I had to move the policy.xml file out of the way but otherwise no obvious problems. Any idea what is causing this or how to debug? I did just realize pasting the code that it makes use of the svg rotate and perhaps that relates to the rotated direction of the labels on the pdf file. Everything else looked right although the y-axis and legend is
now misplaced so I guess there are other problems too. I can post the whole svg if anyone is interested.

Thanks.

The code display is not quite right but this seems to get the important part, edit for minimized, probably not minimal, example converting to black background, ( first edit that I could get this page to accept lol),

```
    <svg style="overflow: hidden; -moz-user-select: none; cursor: default; position: relative; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1722" version="1.1" height="1010"><desc> test foo</desc><rect fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" style="" stroke="#FFFFFFFF" fill="#FFFFFFFF" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="1010" width="1722" y="0" x="0"></rect>
<text transform="rotate(90,40,570)" font-weight="normal" font-size="40" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="570" x="40" style="text-anchor:end;">Normalized amounts </text><path d="M200 80 L1670 80" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M200 200 L1670 200" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M200 320 L1670 320" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M200 440 L1670 440" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M200 560 L1670 560" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M200 680 L1670 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M200 80 L200 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M270 80 L270 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M340 80 L340 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M410 80 L410 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M480 80 L480 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M550 80 L550 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M620 80 L620 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M690 80 L690 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M760 80 L760 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M830 80 L830 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M900 80 L900 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M970 80 L970 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M1040 80 L1040 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M1110 80 L1110 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M1180 80 L1180 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M1250 80 L1250 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M1320 80 L1320 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M1390 80 L1390 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M1460 80 L1460 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M1530 80 L1530 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M1600 80 L1600 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path d="M1670 80 L1670 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<path fill="none" d="M200 80 L295 680 L360 680 L360 680 L520 680 L520 380 L575 680 L645 680 L715 680 L785 680 L855 680 L925 680 L995 680 L1065 680 L1135 680 L1205 680 L1275 380 L1345 680 L1415 680 L1485 680 L1555 380 L1625 380 L1690 680" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="2"/>
<path fill="none" d="M200 520 L295 400 L360 480 L360 680 L520 680 L520 480 L575 440.001 L645 500 L715 560 L785 500 L855 560 L925 440.001 L995 500 L1065 500 L1135 340 L1205 500 L1275 80 L1345 400 L1415 320.001 L1485 320.001 L1555 380.001 L1625 324.001 L1690 400" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="5,5"/>
<path fill="none" d="M200 465.714 L295 80 L360 294.287 L360 680 L520 680 L520 508.571 L575 380 L645 680 L715 680 L785 680 L855 680 L925 680 L995 680 L1065 680 L1135 680 L1205 680 L1275 680 L1345 680 L1415 680 L1485 594.286 L1555 380 L1625 380 L1690 422.857" stroke="green" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="5"/>
<path fill="none" d="M200 680 L295 680 L360 680 L360 680 L520 680 L520 680 L575 680 L645 680 L715 680 L785 680 L855 680 L925 680 L995 680 L1065 680 L1135 680 L1205 680 L1275 680 L1345 680 L1415 680 L1485 680 L1555 80 L1625 241.429 L1690 412.143" stroke="blue" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="5"/>
<path fill="none" d="M200 680 L295 680 L360 680 L360 680 L520 680 L520 680 L575 680 L645 680 L715 680 L785 680 L855 680 L925 680 L995 680 L1065 486.907 L1135 220.815 L1205 234.945 L1275 179.215 L1345 175.29 L1415 104.646 L1485 170.58 L1555 110.925 L1625 80 L1690 414.695" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="2"/>
<path fill="none" d="M200 680 L295 680 L360 680 L360 680 L520 680 L520 680 L575 680 L645 468.235 L715 468.235 L785 341.177 L855 574.118 L925 450.588 L995 468.235 L1065 468.235 L1135 468.235 L1205 468.235 L1275 256.471 L1345 80 L1415 185.882 L1485 185.882 L1555 327.059 L1625 291.765 L1690 680" stroke="blue" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="3,2"/>
<text transform="rotate(81.0029,200,80)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="80" x="200" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,295,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="295" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(-61.9275,360,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="360" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(79.6111,520,380)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380" x="520" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,575,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="575" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,645,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="645" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,715,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="715" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,785,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="785" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,855,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="855" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,925,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="925" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,995,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="995" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,1065,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="1065" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,1135,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="1135" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(-76.866,1205,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="1205" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(76.866,1275,380)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380" x="1275" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,1345,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="1345" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,1415,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="1415" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(-76.866,1485,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="1485" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,1555,380)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380" x="1555" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(77.7749,1625,380)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380" x="1625" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<text transform="rotate(-51.6325,200,520)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="520" x="200" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(50.906,295,400)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="400" x="295" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,360,480)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="480" x="360" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(-36.0266,520,480)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="480" x="520" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(40.6009,575,440.001)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="440.001" x="575" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(40.6013,645,500)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="500" x="645" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(-40.6013,715,560)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="560" x="715" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(40.6013,785,500)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="500" x="785" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(-59.7434,855,560)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="560" x="855" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(40.6009,925,440.001)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="440.001" x="925" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,995,500)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="500" x="995" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(-66.3706,1065,500)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="500" x="1065" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(66.3706,1135,340)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="340" x="1135" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(-80.5377,1205,500)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="500" x="1205" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(77.6609,1275,80)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="80" x="1275" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(-48.8139,1345,400)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="400" x="1345" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,1415,320.001)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="320.001" x="1415" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(40.6014,1485,320.001)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="320.001" x="1485" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(-38.6598,1555,380.001)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380.001" x="1555" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(49.4606,1625,324.001)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="324.001" x="1625" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(-76.1637,200,465.714)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="465.714" x="200" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
<text transform="rotate(73.1258,295,80)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="80" x="295" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
<text transform="rotate(53.2523,360,294.287)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="294.287" x="360" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
<text transform="rotate(-66.8398,520,508.571)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="508.571" x="520" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
<text transform="rotate(76.866,575,380)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380" x="575" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,645,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="645" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,715,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="715" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,785,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="785" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,855,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="855" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,925,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="925" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
<text transform="rotate(-71.9095,1485,594.286)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="594.286" x="1485" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,1555,380)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380" x="1555" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
<text transform="rotate(33.3985,1625,380)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380" x="1625" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
<text transform="rotate(-70.0734,995,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="995" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
<text transform="rotate(-75.2613,1065,486.907)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="486.907" x="1065" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
<text transform="rotate(11.412,1135,220.815)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="220.815" x="1135" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
<text transform="rotate(-38.5246,1205,234.945)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="234.945" x="1205" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
<text transform="rotate(-3.20952,1275,179.215)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="179.215" x="1275" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45.2623,1345,175.29)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="175.29" x="1345" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
<text transform="rotate(43.2867,1415,104.646)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="104.646" x="1415" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
<text transform="rotate(-40.4381,1485,170.58)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="170.58" x="1485" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
<text transform="rotate(-23.8353,1555,110.925)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="110.925" x="1555" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,480,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="480" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,490,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="490" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,500,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="500" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,510,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="510" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,520,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="520" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-10-07</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,560,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="560" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-10-11</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,620,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="620" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,630,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="630" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-10-18</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,640,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="640" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,650,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="650" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,710,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="710" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,770,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="770" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-11-01</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,780,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="780" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,840,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="840" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-11-08</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,910,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="910" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-11-15</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,980,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="980" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-11-22</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1050,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1050" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-11-29</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1120,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1120" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-12-06</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1180,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1180" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1190,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1190" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-12-13</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1260,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1260" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-12-20</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1270,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1270" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1330,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1330" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-12-27</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1390,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1390" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1400,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1400" style="text-anchor:end;">2019-01-03</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1470,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1470" style="text-anchor:end;">2019-01-10</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1480,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1480" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1490,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1490" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1540,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1540" style="text-anchor:end;">2019-01-17</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1550,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1550" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1560,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1560" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1570,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1570" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1580,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1580" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1590,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1590" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1600,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1600" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1610,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1610" style="text-anchor:end;">2019-01-24</text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1620,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1620" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1630,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1630" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1640,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1640" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1650,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1650" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1660,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1660" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1670,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1670" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
<text transform="rotate(-45,1680,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1680" style="text-anchor:end;">2019-01-31</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,930,920)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="920" x="930" style="text-anchor:center;"> All dates approximate</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,180,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="680" x="180" style="text-anchor:end;">0</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,180,560)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="560" x="180" style="text-anchor:end;">0.2</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,180,440)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="440" x="180" style="text-anchor:end;">0.4</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,180,320)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="320" x="180" style="text-anchor:end;">0.6</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,180,200)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="200" x="180" style="text-anchor:end;">0.8</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,180,80)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="80" x="180" style="text-anchor:end;">1</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,400,50)" font-weight="normal" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="50" x="400" style="text-anchor:start;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
<path fill="none" d="M580 55 L670 55" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="5,5"/><text transform="rotate(0,590,50)" font-weight="normal" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" fill="black" y="50" x="590" style="text-anchor:start;">Happy-K2</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,780,50)" font-weight="normal" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" fill="green" y="50" x="780" style="text-anchor:start;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,970,50)" font-weight="normal" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" fill="blue" y="50" x="970" style="text-anchor:start;">Happy-methionine</text>
<text transform="rotate(0,1160,50)" font-weight="normal" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="50" x="1160" style="text-anchor:start;">Happy-threonine</text>
<path fill="none" d="M1340 55 L1510 55" stroke="blue" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="3,2"/><text transform="rotate(0,1350,50)" font-weight="normal" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" fill="blue" y="50" x="1350" style="text-anchor:start;">Happy-tryptophan</text>
</svg>
```

Convert info ( the ldd output too long to post lol),

convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib

This is the pdf converted to jpg for posting,

[slanted x axis normal in input svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnTct.jpg)

Comment: What SVG renderer are you using? Imagmagick internal one XML/MSVG, RSVG delegate or Inkscape in order of increasing quality/accuracy. Try installing Inkscape. Imagemagick will use that automatically.

Comment: Thanks, on further examination makes the same mistakes converting to png also fwiw. It also appears this problem has come up before or variants of it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592085/imagemagick-convert-svg-to-png-not-working-with-rsvg-enabled but I have had good luck on these svg's with earlier version. Will post delegate list in a minute although not sure about getting inkscape yet but maybe gimp.

Comment: Both gimp and inkscape are 200MB or so. I did note this delegate list is only   svg =>          "rsvg-convert' -o '%o' '% while the older working version lists just "rsvg"

Comment: So I installed inkscape and the delegate list did not change but now attempted conversion has the text ok but black background.

Comment: You will need to post a link to your SVG file for me to examine.

Comment: I tried to upload it as an image by editing the original post but it did will not take svg. let me figure out how to do this :)

Comment: You need to post it to some free hosting site that does not change the data/format or zip it first. Then put a link here to where you uploaded it.

Comment: I'm trying to edit it down to post a minimized working example in the original post but it is too long now and the formatting gets messed up complaining the input format is not right...

Comment: It looks like it finally accepted it. It is a hacked up plot that converts from white background , which had converted ok on old version of IM, now giving black background with inkscape installed.

Answer (score 1):

This produces a white background for me in Imagemagick 6.9.10.25 Q16 Mac OSX with Inkscape or RSVG 2.44.10 for the SVG renderer. (Using the Imagemagick internal MSVG renderer does not work properly and jumbles the text.) So try either Inkscape or RSVG delegate. Change your stroke and fill in the first line from #FFFFFFFF (which includes alpha) to #FFFFFF (with no alpha).

```
<svg style="overflow: hidden; -moz-user-select: none; cursor: default; position: relative; background-color: rgb(255,255,255);" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1722" version="1.1" height="1010"><desc> test foo</desc><rect fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" style="" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#FFFFFF" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="1010" width="1722" y="0" x="0"></rect>
    <text transform="rotate(90,40,570)" font-weight="normal" font-size="40" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="570" x="40" style="text-anchor:end;">Normalized amounts </text><path d="M200 80 L1670 80" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M200 200 L1670 200" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M200 320 L1670 320" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M200 440 L1670 440" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M200 560 L1670 560" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M200 680 L1670 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M200 80 L200 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M270 80 L270 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M340 80 L340 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M410 80 L410 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M480 80 L480 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M550 80 L550 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M620 80 L620 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M690 80 L690 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M760 80 L760 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M830 80 L830 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M900 80 L900 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M970 80 L970 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M1040 80 L1040 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M1110 80 L1110 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M1180 80 L1180 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M1250 80 L1250 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M1320 80 L1320 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M1390 80 L1390 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M1460 80 L1460 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M1530 80 L1530 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M1600 80 L1600 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M1670 80 L1670 680" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path fill="none" d="M200 80 L295 680 L360 680 L360 680 L520 680 L520 380 L575 680 L645 680 L715 680 L785 680 L855 680 L925 680 L995 680 L1065 680 L1135 680 L1205 680 L1275 380 L1345 680 L1415 680 L1485 680 L1555 380 L1625 380 L1690 680" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="2"/>
    <path fill="none" d="M200 520 L295 400 L360 480 L360 680 L520 680 L520 480 L575 440.001 L645 500 L715 560 L785 500 L855 560 L925 440.001 L995 500 L1065 500 L1135 340 L1205 500 L1275 80 L1345 400 L1415 320.001 L1485 320.001 L1555 380.001 L1625 324.001 L1690 400" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="5,5"/>
    <path fill="none" d="M200 465.714 L295 80 L360 294.287 L360 680 L520 680 L520 508.571 L575 380 L645 680 L715 680 L785 680 L855 680 L925 680 L995 680 L1065 680 L1135 680 L1205 680 L1275 680 L1345 680 L1415 680 L1485 594.286 L1555 380 L1625 380 L1690 422.857" stroke="green" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="5"/>
    <path fill="none" d="M200 680 L295 680 L360 680 L360 680 L520 680 L520 680 L575 680 L645 680 L715 680 L785 680 L855 680 L925 680 L995 680 L1065 680 L1135 680 L1205 680 L1275 680 L1345 680 L1415 680 L1485 680 L1555 80 L1625 241.429 L1690 412.143" stroke="blue" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="5"/>
    <path fill="none" d="M200 680 L295 680 L360 680 L360 680 L520 680 L520 680 L575 680 L645 680 L715 680 L785 680 L855 680 L925 680 L995 680 L1065 486.907 L1135 220.815 L1205 234.945 L1275 179.215 L1345 175.29 L1415 104.646 L1485 170.58 L1555 110.925 L1625 80 L1690 414.695" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="2"/>
    <path fill="none" d="M200 680 L295 680 L360 680 L360 680 L520 680 L520 680 L575 680 L645 468.235 L715 468.235 L785 341.177 L855 574.118 L925 450.588 L995 468.235 L1065 468.235 L1135 468.235 L1205 468.235 L1275 256.471 L1345 80 L1415 185.882 L1485 185.882 L1555 327.059 L1625 291.765 L1690 680" stroke="blue" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="3,2"/>
    <text transform="rotate(81.0029,200,80)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="80" x="200" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,295,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="295" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-61.9275,360,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="360" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(79.6111,520,380)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380" x="520" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,575,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="575" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,645,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="645" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,715,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="715" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,785,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="785" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,855,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="855" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,925,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="925" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,995,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="995" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,1065,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="1065" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,1135,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="1135" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-76.866,1205,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="1205" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(76.866,1275,380)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380" x="1275" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,1345,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="1345" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,1415,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="1415" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-76.866,1485,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="1485" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,1555,380)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380" x="1555" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(77.7749,1625,380)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380" x="1625" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-51.6325,200,520)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="520" x="200" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(50.906,295,400)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="400" x="295" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,360,480)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="480" x="360" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-36.0266,520,480)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="480" x="520" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(40.6009,575,440.001)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="440.001" x="575" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(40.6013,645,500)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="500" x="645" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-40.6013,715,560)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="560" x="715" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(40.6013,785,500)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="500" x="785" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-59.7434,855,560)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="560" x="855" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(40.6009,925,440.001)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="440.001" x="925" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,995,500)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="500" x="995" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-66.3706,1065,500)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="500" x="1065" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(66.3706,1135,340)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="340" x="1135" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-80.5377,1205,500)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="500" x="1205" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(77.6609,1275,80)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="80" x="1275" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-48.8139,1345,400)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="400" x="1345" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,1415,320.001)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="320.001" x="1415" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(40.6014,1485,320.001)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="320.001" x="1485" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-38.6598,1555,380.001)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380.001" x="1555" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(49.4606,1625,324.001)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="324.001" x="1625" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-76.1637,200,465.714)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="465.714" x="200" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
    <text transform="rotate(73.1258,295,80)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="80" x="295" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
    <text transform="rotate(53.2523,360,294.287)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="294.287" x="360" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-66.8398,520,508.571)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="508.571" x="520" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
    <text transform="rotate(76.866,575,380)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380" x="575" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,645,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="645" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,715,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="715" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,785,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="785" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,855,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="855" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,925,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="925" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-71.9095,1485,594.286)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="594.286" x="1485" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,1555,380)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380" x="1555" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
    <text transform="rotate(33.3985,1625,380)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="380" x="1625" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-70.0734,995,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="680" x="995" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-75.2613,1065,486.907)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="486.907" x="1065" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
    <text transform="rotate(11.412,1135,220.815)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="220.815" x="1135" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-38.5246,1205,234.945)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="234.945" x="1205" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-3.20952,1275,179.215)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="179.215" x="1275" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45.2623,1345,175.29)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="175.29" x="1345" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
    <text transform="rotate(43.2867,1415,104.646)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="104.646" x="1415" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-40.4381,1485,170.58)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="170.58" x="1485" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-23.8353,1555,110.925)" font-weight="normal" font-size="2" font-family="Verdana" fill="white" y="110.925" x="1555" style="text-anchor:center;">Happy-threonine</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,480,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="480" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,490,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="490" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,500,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="500" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,510,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="510" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,520,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="520" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-10-07</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,560,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="560" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-10-11</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,620,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="620" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,630,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="630" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-10-18</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,640,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="640" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,650,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="650" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,710,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="710" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,770,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="770" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-11-01</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,780,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="780" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,840,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="840" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-11-08</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,910,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="910" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-11-15</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,980,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="980" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-11-22</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1050,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1050" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-11-29</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1120,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1120" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-12-06</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1180,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1180" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1190,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1190" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-12-13</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1260,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1260" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-12-20</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1270,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1270" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1330,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1330" style="text-anchor:end;">2018-12-27</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1390,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1390" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1400,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1400" style="text-anchor:end;">2019-01-03</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1470,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1470" style="text-anchor:end;">2019-01-10</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1480,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1480" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1490,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1490" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1540,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1540" style="text-anchor:end;">2019-01-17</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1550,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1550" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1560,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1560" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1570,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1570" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1580,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1580" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1590,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1590" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1600,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1600" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1610,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1610" style="text-anchor:end;">2019-01-24</text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1620,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1620" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1630,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1630" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1640,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1640" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1650,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1650" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1660,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1660" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1670,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1670" style="text-anchor:end;"></text>
    <text transform="rotate(-45,1680,720)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="720" x="1680" style="text-anchor:end;">2019-01-31</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,930,920)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="920" x="930" style="text-anchor:center;"> All dates approximate</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,180,680)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="680" x="180" style="text-anchor:end;">0</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,180,560)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="560" x="180" style="text-anchor:end;">0.2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,180,440)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="440" x="180" style="text-anchor:end;">0.4</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,180,320)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="320" x="180" style="text-anchor:end;">0.6</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,180,200)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="200" x="180" style="text-anchor:end;">0.8</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,180,80)" font-weight="normal" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="80" x="180" style="text-anchor:end;">1</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,400,50)" font-weight="normal" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="50" x="400" style="text-anchor:start;">Happy-Ivermectin</text>
    <path fill="none" d="M580 55 L670 55" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="5,5"/><text transform="rotate(0,590,50)" font-weight="normal" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" fill="black" y="50" x="590" style="text-anchor:start;">Happy-K2</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,780,50)" font-weight="normal" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" fill="green" y="50" x="780" style="text-anchor:start;">Happy-doxycycline</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,970,50)" font-weight="normal" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" fill="blue" y="50" x="970" style="text-anchor:start;">Happy-methionine</text>
    <text transform="rotate(0,1160,50)" font-weight="normal" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" fill="red" y="50" x="1160" style="text-anchor:start;">Happy-threonine</text>
    <path fill="none" d="M1340 55 L1510 55" stroke="blue" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="3,2"/><text transform="rotate(0,1350,50)" font-weight="normal" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" fill="blue" y="50" x="1350" style="text-anchor:start;">Happy-tryptophan</text>
    </svg>
```

```
convert test.svg test.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah thanks, changing the alphas made it white. I'll have to look at that. I don't convert real often but never saw this problem with the old IM convert and the old and new eog produce white with the FF alpha svg. fwiw.

Comment: I am not an SVG expert. You may have some other issues with your SVG file causing the problem and would need some one more experienced than I to point out the issues. I do not think it is an Imagemagick issue as other tools were displaying it as black including Photoshop.

Comment: The header stuff I copied from something else and never looked at it:) This comes out of my c++ code after I had problems with dates and funny things in R. I thought the blank text may have confused something and just changed my code to stop outputting that but have not determined it to be a problem. Earlier I  saw a problem with text of size 1 anchor  point but was told it was not a problem,  I'll have to look into that again.