# PHP Imagick library not converting SVG charts colors to jpg

Tags: php, svg, charts, imagick, fusioncharts

I am using Imagick to convert my `SVG` to `JPG`. The `SVG` is actually a chart generated with `FusionCharts` library. The image is created but my chart is not properly converted to image. It means the colors are not converted as well as the BARS of the charts. First look how my chart looks like

[image]

But when I convert the `SVG` of this chart using `Imagick` `PHP` library it generated the image which looks like

[image]

Iam using the following code to convert the `SVG` to `JPG`

```
 $svg = $this->_request->getPost('svg');
 $svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.$svg;
 $im->readImageBlob($svg);
 header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
 $im->setImageFormat("jpeg");
 $im->writeImage($dir.'/'.$id.'.jpg');/*(or .jpg)*/
 $im->clear();
 $im->destroy();
```

I am getting `SVG` at `Rendered` event of `Fusionchart` like

```
  myChart.addEventListener( "Rendered", function(evt, args) {
        var svg = myChart.ref.getSVGString();
    });
```

And my SVG looks like

```
 <svg style="overflow: hidden; -moz-user-select: none; cursor: default; position: relative; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="480" version="1.1" height="283"><desc>framework 3.3.1.sr2.19840</desc><defs><clipPath id="B0590631-A9A1-4149-BEF9-2DE5773DC243"><rect transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" height="241" width="403" y="15" x="62"></rect></clipPath></defs><g class="red-background-0"><rect fill-opacity="0.6" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="0.5" style="" stroke="#545454" fill="#ffffff" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="283" width="480" y="0" x="0"></rect></g><g class="red-canvas-6"><rect stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;" stroke="#969899" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="242" width="404" y="14.5" x="61.5"></rect><rect fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="0" style="" stroke="none" fill="#ffffff" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="241" width="403" y="15" x="62"></rect></g><g class="red-axisbottom-9"><g class="red-x-axis-bands-12"></g><g class="red-y-axis-bands-18"><rect stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" style="" stroke="#000" fill="#d8dcc5" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="48.20000000000002" width="403" y="159.6" x="62"></rect><rect stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" style="" stroke="#000" fill="#d8dcc5" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="48.19999999999999" width="403" y="63.19999999999999" x="62"></rect></g><g class="red-y-axis-bands-24"></g><g class="red-x-axis-lines-14"></g><g class="red-y-axis-lines-20"><path shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.45" d="M62,208.5L465,208.5" stroke="#ffffff" fill="none" style="shape-rendering: crispedges;"></path><path shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.45" d="M62,160.5L465,160.5" stroke="#ffffff" fill="none" style="shape-rendering: crispedges;"></path><path shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.45" d="M62,111.5L465,111.5" stroke="#ffffff" fill="none" style="shape-rendering: crispedges;"></path><path shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.45" d="M62,63.5L465,63.5" stroke="#ffffff" fill="none" style="shape-rendering: crispedges;"></path></g><g class="red-y-axis-lines-26"></g><g class="red-x-axis-labels-16"><text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" font-weight="bold" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#000000" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle" y="268" x="112.375" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan x="112.375" dy="-2">Mar-13</tspan></text><text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" font-weight="bold" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#000000" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle" y="268" x="213.125" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan x="213.125" dy="-2">Dec-12</tspan></text><text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" font-weight="bold" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#000000" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle" y="268" x="313.875" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan x="313.875" dy="-2">Nov-12</tspan></text><text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" font-weight="bold" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#000000" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle" y="268" x="414.625" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan x="414.625" dy="-2">Oct-12</tspan></text></g><g class="red-y-axis-labels-22"><text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#000000" stroke="none" text-anchor="end" y="256" x="58" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px;"><tspan x="58" dy="3">$0</tspan></text><text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#000000" stroke="none" text-anchor="end" y="207.8" x="58" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px;"><tspan x="58" dy="2.9992187500000114">$300</tspan></text><text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#000000" stroke="none" text-anchor="end" y="159.6" x="58" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px;"><tspan x="58" dy="2.9984374999999943">$600</tspan></text><text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#000000" stroke="none" text-anchor="end" y="111.39999999999998" x="58" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px;"><tspan x="58" dy="3.0015624999999773">$900</tspan></text><text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#000000" stroke="none" text-anchor="end" y="63.19999999999999" x="58" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px;"><tspan x="58" dy="3.0007812499999886">$1.2K</tspan></text><text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#000000" stroke="none" text-anchor="end" y="14.999999999999972" x="58" style="text-anchor: end; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px;"><tspan x="58" dy="2.9999999999999716">$1.5K</tspan></text></g><g class="red-y-axis-labels-28"></g><g class="red-axis-name-29"><text transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,17.5,136)" font-weight="bold" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#000000" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle" y="0" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan x="0" dy="8">Millions</tspan></text></g></g><g class="red-dataset-1"><g class="red-shadows-47"><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="5" stroke-opacity="0.05" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.05; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="87.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="0.1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.1; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="87.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.15; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="87.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="5" stroke-opacity="0.05" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.05; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="188.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="0.1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.1; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="188.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.15; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="188.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="5" stroke-opacity="0.05" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.05; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="288.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="0.1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.1; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="288.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.15; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="288.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="5" stroke-opacity="0.05" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.05; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="389.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="0.1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.1; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="389.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.15; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="389.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="5" stroke-opacity="0.05" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.05; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="87.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="0.1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.1; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="87.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.15; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="87.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="5" stroke-opacity="0.05" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.05; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="188.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="0.1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.1; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="188.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.15; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="188.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="5" stroke-opacity="0.05" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.05; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="288.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="0.1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.1; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="288.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.15; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="288.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="5" stroke-opacity="0.05" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.05; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="389.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="0.1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.1; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="389.5"></rect><rect shape-rendering="default" stroke-linecap="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,1)" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" style="stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-opacity: 0.15; stroke-linecap: round;" stroke="#404040" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="389.5"></rect></g><g clip-path="url('http://test.hbinsights.com/admin/scorecard/kpipdf/cid/1/dtype/1#B0590631-A9A1-4149-BEF9-2DE5773DC243')" style="" class="red-columns-48"><rect stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;" stroke="#8a8a8a" fill="#00955d" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="87.5"></rect><rect stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;" stroke="#8a8a8a" fill="#00955d" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="188.5"></rect><rect stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;" stroke="#8a8a8a" fill="#00955d" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="288.5"></rect><rect stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;" stroke="#8a8a8a" fill="#00955d" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="389.5"></rect><rect stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;" stroke="#8a8a8a" fill="#014a7f" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="87.5"></rect><rect stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;" stroke="#8a8a8a" fill="#014a7f" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="188.5"></rect><rect stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;" stroke="#8a8a8a" fill="#014a7f" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="288.5"></rect><rect stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" style="stroke-linejoin: miter;" stroke="#8a8a8a" fill="#014a7f" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="0" width="50" y="256.5" x="389.5"></rect></g></g><g class="red-axistop-10"><g class="red-x-axis-bands-11"></g><g class="red-y-axis-bands-17"></g><g class="red-y-axis-bands-23"></g><g class="red-x-axis-lines-13"></g><g class="red-y-axis-lines-19"></g><g class="red-y-axis-lines-25"></g><g class="red-x-axis-labels-15"></g><g class="red-y-axis-labels-21"></g><g class="red-y-axis-labels-27"></g></g><g style="display: none;" class="red-datalabels-5"><text font-weight="bold" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle" y="254.5" x="112.5" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan x="112.5" dy="3">$0.0</tspan></text><text font-weight="bold" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle" y="220.5" x="213.5" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan x="213.5" dy="3">$433.0</tspan></text><text font-weight="bold" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle" y="219" x="313.5" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan x="313.5" dy="3">$449.0</tspan></text><text font-weight="bold" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle" y="222" x="414.5" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan x="414.5" dy="3">$417.0</tspan></text><text font-weight="bold" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle" y="254.5" x="112.5" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan x="112.5" dy="3">$0.0</tspan></text><text font-weight="bold" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle" y="104" x="213.5" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan x="213.5" dy="3">$1024.0</tspan></text><text font-weight="bold" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle" y="110.5" x="313.5" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan x="313.5" dy="3">$912.0</tspan></text><text font-weight="bold" font-size="8px" font-family="Verdana" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle" y="108.5" x="414.5" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan x="414.5" dy="3">$1008.0</tspan></text></g><g class="red-hot-2"></g><g class="red-buttons-4"></g><text font-family="Verdana" font-size="9px" fill-opacity="0.5" fill="#000000" stroke="none" text-anchor="start" y="279" x="6" style="text-anchor: start; font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana; cursor: pointer;"><tspan x="6" dy="-1.3984375">FusionCharts XT Trial</tspan></text></svg>
```

The above svg on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FSF2a/).

Can any body tell and guide me how can I convert my whole chart with all colors and bars to jpg. I have proper checked the `SVG`. It is same that is creating the chart.

**EDITED**

After comments of ERIK, I have come to know that `Fusionchart` render event is not the exact event. Because it is giving `SVG` that is not complete. So Now I my question is what is the exact even of Fusion Chart that chart has completed its animation?

Comment: Could you add the svg output to the question? Also, what version of ImageMagick are you using? There are some known issues with the svg support in ImageMagick, see e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658872/svg-to-png-conversion-with-imagemagick-doesnt-handle-defs.

Comment: You want I put my SVG element?

Comment: @ErikDahlström I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your svg content, it seems you have rects with `height="0"` (looking at the elements inside the group with classname `red-dataset-1`), and I'm assuming that's not what you want? Rects with zero width or height don't render, according to the svg spec.

So, the JPEG output seems correct to me. This suggests that your problem lies with the generation/serialization of the svg itself.

In the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FSF2a/) the elements that are the bars of the chart are clipped away by a clip-path. Why? Because the rects that make up the bars are simply outside the clip-path area. You can set the `y` values to be a bit smaller (e.g `y="50"`), and adjust the `height` values to be non-zero, then you'll start seeing the bars, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Vv3SR/).

Comment: Thanks Erick. Actually I am getting this `SVG` on fusionchart event `Rendered`. But I think this event doesn't give the exact and complete `SVG`.